# Enumerating through an object's properties (string) in C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, properties

Let's say I have many objects and they have many string properties.

Is there a programatic way to go through them and output the propertyname and its value or does it have to be hard coded?

Is there maybe a LINQ way to query an object's properties of type 'string' and to output them?

Do you have to hard code the property names you want to echo?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Use reflection. It's nowhere near as fast as hardcoded property access, but it does what you want.

The following query generates an anonymous type with Name and Value properties for each string-typed property in the object 'myObject':

```
var stringPropertyNamesAndValues = myObject.GetType()
    .GetProperties()
    .Where(pi => pi.PropertyType == typeof(string) && pi.GetGetMethod() != null)
    .Select(pi => new 
    {
        Name = pi.Name,
        Value = pi.GetGetMethod().Invoke(myObject, null)
    });
```

Usage:

```
foreach (var pair in stringPropertyNamesAndValues)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", pair.Name);
    Console.WriteLine("Value: {0}", pair.Value);
}
```

Comment: Instead of pi.GetGetMethod().Invoke(myObject, null) I'd rather use pi.GetValue(myObject, null) - simpler to read.

Answer (score 16):

You can get all the properties of a type by using the `GetProperties` method. You can then filter this list using the LINQ `Where` extension method. Finally you can project the properties using the LINQ `Select` extension method or a convenient shortcut like `ToDictionary`.

If you want to limit the enumeration to properties having of type `String` you can use this code:

```
IDictionary<String, String> dictionary = myObject.GetType()
  .GetProperties()
  .Where(p => p.CanRead && p.PropertyType == typeof(String))
  .ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => (String) p.GetValue(myObject, null));
```

This will create a dictionary that maps property names to property values. As the property type is limited to `String` it is safe to cast the property value to `String` and the type of the returned type is `IDictionary<String, String>`.

If you instead want all properties you can do it like this:

```
IDictionary<String, Object> dictionary = myObject.GetType()
  .GetProperties()
  .Where(p => p.CanRead)
  .ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.GetValue(myObject, null));
```

Answer (score 4):

If your goal is simply to output the data stored in the object's properties using a human-readable format, I prefer to simply serialize the object into JSON format.

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
//...

string output = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(myObject);
```

Answer (score -3):

How about something like this?

```
public string Prop1
{
    get { return dic["Prop1"]; }
    set { dic["Prop1"] = value; }
}

public string Prop2
{
    get { return dic["Prop2"]; }
    set { dic["Prop2"] = value; }
}

private Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> AllProps
{
    get { return dic.GetEnumerator(); }
}
```

Comment: How about we not go back to 1995 and use hashtables as classes?