# enumerate all of property and its value

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Enumerating through an object's properties (string) in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447308/enumerating-through-an-objects-properties-string-in-c)

Can I use reflection to enumerate all the property name and value of an object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be something like below

Say there is a object strList

```
 PropertyInfo[] info = strList.GetType().GetProperties();

        Dictionary<string, object> propNamesAndValues = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        foreach (PropertyInfo pinfo in info)
        {
            propNamesAndValues.Add(pinfo.Name, pinfo.GetValue(strList, null));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var properties = myObj.GetType()
                    .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
var propertyNames = properties.Select(p => p.Name);
var propertyValues = properties.Select(p => p.GetValue(myObj, null));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like this:

```
MyClass aClass = new MyClass();

Type t = aClass.GetType();
PropertyInfo[] pi = t.GetProperties();

foreach (PropertyInfo prop in pi)
    Console.WriteLine("Prop: {0}", prop.Name);
```

Hope it will help you.