# In ASP.net MVC , how to use a dynamic model?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, dynamic, model

I create model from my sql 2008 server database using northwind example.
Model.Order, I want to dynamically use the Order rows, just like `datatable`

```
DataTable a = New DataTable() .
```

.......fill the order data to table a .and then I can use

`a[1]` or `a["orderid"]` to get the data .
    but in mvc 
    Ican just use `Model.Order a = new Model.Order()` 
    ...fill the a with data .
    use `a.OrderID` to get the data

Is there any way to foreach it  with count like

```
 for(int i=0;i<a.count;i++)
    {
      //how to get the data like these way ??
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking you want to give your View an `IEnumerable<T>`. So for example, you do something like:

```
@model IEnumerable<Project.WebUI.Models.Order>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <h1>item.Customername</h1>
}
```

In your controller, you have to create an `IEnumerable<Order>` collection and then pass it along the view. Since the controller is just a C# class, creating the collection will be the same process as you've come to know during previous .NET work.

The only new thing that you have to realize in MVC is that the View is dumb. It doesn't do any code processing, just burps up the information you've given it from the controller into a format you've defined in the view.

Does this make sense?

Comment: I know this ,But I have many tables like order ,so in the control I like to enumerate the order's column ,I don't know the column name ,I like this

Comment: I know this ,But I have many tables like order ,so in the control I like to enumerate the order's column ,I don't know the column name ,I like this in function in control : public string getJsonData<T>(<IList<T> orders){ foreach(var item in orders ) { StrinbBUilder sb = new StringBuilder ; for(int i =0;i<item.count;i++){ sb.append(item[i].toString();}  }. this code is want I want do do ,but it seems impossible  .I  can use ModelMetadata to get the column info and column count ,but I can't use it to dynamic  to get the model data .Anyway ,thanks a lot .

Answer (score 0):

This answer should answer your question

[Enumerating through an object's properties (string) in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447308/enumerating-through-an-objects-properties-string-in-c/1447318#1447318)

with Model.GetProperties() in get a list of all the properties. Then with a foreach you obtain the names and values of them. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

From your replies above it sounds like you want to use the ModelMetadata to display the data for an unknown model type.  I developed Dynamic MVC to do something like this.  Let me know if this helps.

http://dynamicmvc.com