# How to iterate through a ViewModel's properties in the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel

I have a ViewModel with a number of different properties (ie string, int, etc) that I need to iterate through in the controller. What is the best way to do this? Here is the ViewModel's defintion:

```
public class BankListViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string BankName { get; set; }
    public string EPURL { get; set; }
    public string AssociatedTPMBD { get; set; }
    public string Tier { get; set; }
    public List<BankListAgentId> BankListAgentId { get; set; }
    public List<BankListStateCode> BankListStateCode { get; set; }
}
```

I need to omit the two lists, however. Any ideas?

EDIT

The purpose of this process is to pass specific items of the view model into three separate objects. The view model was created to combine properties of three separate SQL tables/Models. I am now trying to divide them up appropriately and add the information to the relevant tables. Right now I'm simply going one by one like so:

```
        BankListMaster banklistmaster = new BankListMaster();
        banklistmaster.AssociatedTPMBD = viewmodel.AssociatedTPMBD;
        banklistmaster.BankName = viewmodel.BankName;
```

Comment: reflexion? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/531384/how-to-loop-through-all-the-properties-of-a-class

Comment: What are you trying to do with properties you iterate over? Read values? Read their names?

Comment: The intent is not very clear.  What do you mean by 'iterate through'?  Why is this necessary?  Why not just read the properties?

Comment: or this one reflection + Linq : http://stackoverflow.com/q/1447308/1236044

Comment: sorry, edited my question to better explain

Comment: Why don't you structure your viewmodel in first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although it's not clear why you would need to iterate over the properties instead of just reading their vaules, you could accomplish this using reflection

```
var model = new BankListViewModel();
PropertyInfo[] properties = model.GetType().GetProperties();
foreach (var property in properties)
{
    if (property.GetType() != typeof(List<BankListAgentId>))
            {
                //do your thing here
            }

}
```